# Can I move arbitrary function inside integral?

Tags: integration, variational-analysis

I have a term $\delta g\int_V dV$, where $\delta g$ is the variation of a continuous function g(x,y,z) and $V$ is an arbitrary volume of integration over some physical 3D body. Moreover, $\delta g=0$ is true on parts of the surface bounding $V$.

My question: Does $\delta g\int_V dV=\int_V \delta g dV$ hold?

My initial reasoning was that it should **hold** because, since $V$ and $\delta g$ are arbitrary, we can always choose $V$ such that the equality is true whether $\delta g$ is a constant or not.

Needless to say I am not a mathematician so if you are kind enough to answer, and although I usually enjoy technical proofs, please keep it as simple as you can.

Thank you!

Best regards

Comment: To make sure I understand, $\delta g$ is a function on the surface $V$, and $dV$ is a particular (fixed) measure on $V$. Is that right?

Comment: V is an arbitrary volume of some physical object and dV is just the variable of integration. $\delta g$ is defined at every point in V. I hope that answered your question, I'm not familiar with the terms you used, like "measure" for example.

Comment: $\delta g(x,y,z)\int_VdV$ is a function on $x,y,z$ and $\int_V\delta g(x,y,z)dV$ is a scalar. You cannot even compare them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are asking to compare something like
$$ f(x) \int_0^1 1 \;dt \quad \text{and} \quad \int_0^1 f(t) dt.$$
I have chosen to use $dt$ instead of $dx$ to emphasize the fact that the thing on the left is a function of $x$, while the thing on the right is a constant. I know the original question was phrased in 3d, but I don't think the dimension is important here.

They are not equal, unless $f(x)$ is actually a constant function $c$.

Comment: Thank you. I read through my notes again and realized what the error was in my calculations leading up to this question.